# How to retrieve value from subquery in main query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to retrieve dtmPost in the main query. I tried a.dtmPost after ai.strID, but it didn't work. I am not sure whether or not it's possible to do so without making big changes. Is my assumption correct?

```
SELECT  p.strMed,
    d.lngAKey,
    ai.strID

FROM    tblP p RIGHT JOIN tblV v 
ON  p.lngPKey  = v.lngPKey INNER JOIN tblD d 
ON  v.lngVKey  = d.lngVKey INNER JOIN tblAI ai
ON  d.lngAKey = ai.lngAKey

WHERE   dtmEff between

    (SELECT MAX(a.dtmPost) AS dtmPost

    FROM    (SELECT dtmPost 
        FROM    tblPBIH pbih 
        WHERE   pbih.lngAKey    = d.lngAKey 

        UNION   

        SELECT  dtmPost 
        FROM    tblPBI pbi 
        WHERE   pbi.lngAKey     = d.lngAKey 
        ) a)

AND (SELECT MAX(a.dtmPost) AS dtmPost 

    FROM    (SELECT DATEADD(D, 10, pbih.dtmPost) AS dtmPost 
        FROM    tblPBIH pbih 
        WHERE   pbih.lngAKey    = d.lngAKey 

        UNION   

        SELECT  DATEADD(D, 10, pbi.dtmPost) AS dtmPost 
        FROM    tblPBI pbi 
        WHERE   pbi.lngAKey     = d.lngAKey 
        ) a)
```

I came up with the following and it works, but is there any other way that is better?

```
DECLARE @X date, @Y date

SET @X =(SELECT MAX(a.dtmPost) AS dtmPost

    FROM    (SELECT dtmPost 
        FROM    tblPBIH pbih 
        WHERE   pbih.lngAKey    = d.lngAKey 

        UNION   

        SELECT  dtmPost 
        FROM    tblPBI pbi 
        WHERE   pbi.lngAKey     = d.lngAKey 
        ) a)

SET @Y =(SELECT MAX(a.dtmPost) AS dtmPost 

    FROM    (SELECT DATEADD(D, 10, pbih.dtmPost) AS dtmPost 
        FROM    tblPBIH pbih 
        WHERE   pbih.lngAKey    = d.lngAKey 

        UNION   

        SELECT  DATEADD(D, 10, pbi.dtmPost) AS dtmPost 
        FROM    tblPBI pbi 
        WHERE   pbi.lngAKey     = d.lngAKey 
        ) a)

SELECT  p.strMed,
    d.lngAKey,
    ai.strID,
    @X AS dtmBackDate

FROM    tblP p RIGHT JOIN tblV v 
ON  p.lngPKey  = v.lngPKey INNER JOIN tblD d 
ON  v.lngVKey  = d.lngVKey INNER JOIN tblAI ai
ON  d.lngAKey = ai.lngAKey

WHERE   dtmEff > @X
AND     dtmEff <= @Y
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: And you expect we understand your query without any example huh? You are not exposing your question to yourself, but a group who need context to understand what are you talking about

Comment: It is possible to create the two unions as either temp tables or CTE's and then include dtmPost in the main query and use them for the subquery too...which might be more efficient.

Comment: In general the procedural version using variables would be considered inferior. You should always use set-based thinking and do it all in the one place. I would be surprised if a better solution isn't available, but as the earlier comments say we would need some sample data.

Comment: Wish I could include the data (it's sensitive one) to make the question clearer. Thanks a lot for all you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see the only difference between your 2 dates is 10 days, so there is absolutely no reason to do the query twice.

This is a version of the query reworked. As we have no test data I have no idea if there are typos, but you should get the idea. You could else write it using CTEs if you prefer.

I also swapped your right join to a left join as I personally never use right join, but that might just be personal preference.

```
SELECT  p.strMed,
    d.lngAKey,
    ai.strID,
    dates.dtmPost AS dtmBackDate
FROM tblV v  
INNER JOIN tblD d ON  v.lngVKey  = d.lngVKey 
INNER JOIN tblAI ai ON  d.lngAKey = ai.lngAKey
LEFT JOIN tblP p ON  p.lngPKey  = v.lngPKey
INNER JOIN (
        select  lngAKey, max(dtmPost) dtmPost from 
        (
            SELECT  lngAKey, dtmPost 
            FROM    tblPBIH pbih 
            WHERE   pbih.lngAKey

            UNION   

            SELECT  lngAKey, dtmPost 
            FROM    tblPBI pbi 
            WHERE   pbi.lngAKey
        ) q
        group by lngAKey
        ) dates on dates.lngAKey=d.lngAKey
WHERE   dtmEff > dates.dtmPost
AND     dtmEff <= DATEADD(D, 10, dates.dtmPost)
```

Comment: @TomC, surely that's max(dates.dtmpost) in the WHERE clause?

Comment: I cam see than @TomC but what I am getting at is that the original code compared dtmEff with the max dtmpost (a single value) and the max dtmpost in 10 months (also a single value). Your code seems to suggest the dtmEff should be less than or equal to all the rows in dtmPost that are 10 months after their equivalents in the original dtmPost column. Not to worry,